# angularjs getdate not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm fairly new to javascript and angularjs so please bear with me. I am having issues when attempting to interact with the Date object. I assume that Date is a javascript object. However when running .getDate() on a Date object i get a date of 1970.

My code is shown below:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  var DateController = function($scope) {
        $scope.today = new Date();
        $scope.tomorrow = $scope.today.getDay() +1;
  };

  app.controller("DateController", DateController);
}());
```

This is really basic, however l do not understand why I am getting that date.
I also get the same behavior when working with some other default javascript Date functions. An explanation would also be appreciated.

I have created a plunk for convience: [Take me to the plunk!](http://plnkr.co/edit/7BPSYk79UfdCa6kVDUbC?p=preview)

Comment: The two answers you have show you the correct way to handle dates. You are getting a date in 1970 because javascript time is measured in milliseconds from midnight January 1, 1970 UTC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. So that date is the zero date for Javascript.

Comment: also, you need to use `getDate()` not `getDay()`, if you are trying to get the entire date

Comment: Yeah my bad, i'll change that. I initially meant getDate(), it results in the same outcome though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cADCRJYDjL9PwU0FAzJm?p=preview)

you should use setDate to change date value

your new controller should be like this:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  var DateController = function($scope) {
        $scope.today = new Date();
        $scope.tomorrow = new Date();
        $scope.tomorrow = $scope.tomorrow.setDate($scope.tomorrow.getDate() +1);
  };

  app.controller("DateController", DateController);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works fine as well but will have to give props to Adrian as he was first.

Comment: @scripton not really, if you look to the answer time you will see that I answered 12 mins ago and he answered 8 mins ago. But ok.

Answer (score 1):

Following from editing your plunk.. more on [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);

  var DateController = function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();

    // elaborated code for illustration
    var nextDay = new Date($scope.today);
    nextDay.setDate($scope.today.getDate()+1);

    $scope.tomorrow = nextDay;
  };

  app.controller("DateController", DateController);
}());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work just fine, can't believe i missed that! Will mark as you were the first one and + for the reference to the Date object.